# Instantiate теряет значения класса при попытки инстантиировать его - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать инвентарь, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при копировании GameObject'а из инстанса класса, теряется информация (в скопированном инстансе). Пример:

```
public void DropItem(Item item)
{
    Debug.Log(item.Count);         //Count = 6

    Item go = Instantiate(item);
    Debug.Log(go.Count);            //Count = 1 (as default)
}
```

Просто не пойму почему.

Как можно не терять значения класса Item, инстантиируя класс?

Item.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Id = "item_id";
    public string Name = "Item name";
    
    public int Count = 1;
    public int MaxCount = 16;

    public Sprite Sprite;
}
```

Comment: что такое итем? Префаб?

Comment: Instantiate создает клон объекта, не делает что-либо с исходным. А что такое `Count`?

Comment: @Andrew Item - это класс, наследуемый от MonoBehaviour, и если его инстантиировать, то появится предмет на сцене

Comment: @aepot ```item``` изначально приходит с каким то состоянием. Count - число которое находится в Item'е. Но проблема в том, что он не копирует, а как будто берёт значение из конструктора Item

Comment: Покажите этот класс `Item` в вопросе. Скорее всего проблема именно в конструкторе.

Comment: Кинь код итема, без него вряд ли что подскажут

Comment: @aepot Добавил класс ```Item```

Comment: Что будет, если убрать значения по умолчанию для полей? Вроде вюнити принято их задавать другим образом.

Comment: Не, в юнити именно так стандартные значения для инициализации и задаются. Можно только украшательства для инспектора задавать. Вроде ограничений по рейнджу, дополнительных надписей и подобного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ благодарность **aepot** за то что заставил перепроверить свои слова и не дать солгать в ответе ]

Я скопировал твой класс себе в пустой проэкт и написал код которым проверял работу Instantiate.

Разместил на сцене два обьекта - один твой итем, который и назвал итемом. И второй - тест. Для проверки работы инстансиейта.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var item = GameObject.Find("Item");

        var baseCopy = Instantiate(item);
        var baseCopyInfo = baseCopy.GetComponent<Item>();
        
        var itemInfo = item.GetComponent<Item>();
        // меняем стандартное значение
        itemInfo.Count = 50;

        var copy = Instantiate(item);
        var copyInfo = copy.GetComponent<Item>();

        var componentCopy = Instantiate(itemInfo);

        Debug.Log("BaseCopyInfo " + baseCopyInfo.Count);
        Debug.Log("ItemInfo " + itemInfo.Count);
        Debug.Log("50 copy Info " + copyInfo.Count);
        Debug.Log("component copy Info " + componentCopy.Count);


    }
```

информация из лога:

> BaseCopyInfo 1
>
> ItemInfo 50
>
> 50 copy Info 50
>
> component copy Info 50

Смею предположить что если такова проблема и есть у тебя в проэкте, то она кроется извне метода Instantiate и извне метода DropItem.

Думаю что для дебага тебе нужно использовать метод OnValidate  - это метод который сделит за изменениями параметров в обьекте. Если значение любого параметра было изменено - он вызывается. Таким макаром ты сможешь отследить момент, когда именно значение реально у тебя меняется.

Comment: А ```ICloneable``` при таком случае может помочь?

Comment: Если чесно, не уверен. Вероятнее всего нет, но могу и ошибаться. Поищи больше информации по запросу который я написал в ответе.

Comment: Эмм, C# вроде из коробки такое умеет https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netcore-3.1 Или это другое?

Comment: @aepot я не уверен потому что не уверен как именно работает юнити внутри. Он может создать копию самого геймобджекта в оперативной памяти, но не поместить его на сцену, например. Что бы уверенно сказать поможет ли клонирование обьекта неродными для юнити методами нужно глубже понимать как работает юнити и метод Instantiate в частности. Ну или как минимум нужно сидеть и экспериментировать)

Comment: Все таки юнити это надстройка на шарп. И юнити накладывает целый ряд ограничений на использование шарпа. Например на использование версии языка) Вобщем я гадать не возьмусь. Или автору проверять экспериментально или же гуглить глубже.

Comment: Согласно [доке](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) - _When you clone a `GameObject` or `Component`, all child objects and components are also cloned with their properties set like those of the original object._ Вы уверены в правильности вашего ответа? Если нет, то лучше удалите, чтобы не сбивать никого с толку.

Comment: @aepot и там в примере в этой документации - префаб. С префаба оно скопирует ровно те значения, которые записаны в префабе.  Учитывая что автор далеко не единственный кто столкнулся с задачей клонирования вместе со значениями параметров обьекта - могу предположить что документация недостаточно точно написала что копируются значения префаба вместе с параметрами) Ну и инициализируется со стандартными знаениями GameObject.

Comment: Сейчас у меня нету возможности проверить свое предположение в юнити, к сожалению

Comment: Еще раз, вы уверены, или предполагаете? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html Ответы-гипотезы не имеют смысла на StackOverflow. Предположения лучше писать в комментариях, а не в ответах.

Comment: Еще как вариант - сделать префаб из обьекта на лету и именно его и инстанциировать

Comment: 10 минут. пересяду за другой компьютер и перепроверю все.

Comment: @aepot да, ты оказался прав. А я змолол фигню. Удаляю ответ, делаю новый вместо него

Comment: Лучше этот отредактировать. И отписать автору потом.

Comment: @jaboid  прошу прощения за обман в первом ответе, я не специально :) Я обновил информацию в своем ответе как тебе найти когда на самом деле изменяется параметр что бы ты отдебажился.